# create a google map marker containing price

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am creating a real estate website with a map showing houses with their price. I need a marker like the marker used on airbnb.com. How can I do it? I am using  this:

[image: pin]

I need something like this:

[image: What i want]

Comment: Cool story. What have you tried and what's actually wrong with your code? (assuming you have even attempted this yourself)

Comment: the image i post is what i want to have, i am using now a normal marker i use this code:
 marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: markers[i][3],
con: (on) ? 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=V|EC2A8C|000000' :      'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=L|BDD73C|000000'
        });

Comment: Although not sure if it will solve your problem.but just for try. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/custom-markers

Comment: Please post your code. But first, see [How to complete a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a custom icon, like the one below - use another image URL for your needs.

```
var image = {
          url: 'http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/swatchImages/35/04/04a604de-8b52-4cd8-a394-6286f00b438d_35.jpg',
          // This marker is 35 pixels wide by 35 pixels high.
          size: new google.maps.Size(35, 35),
          // The origin for this image is (0, 0).
          origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
          // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at (0, 32).
          anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 35)
        };
```

Then when creating the marker, use the *image* object as the *icon* property. For more information see the [maps API documentation for complex icons](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#complex_icons).

See it in action in the snippet below:

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.385932, 2.178678),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var image = {
          url: 'http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/swatchImages/35/04/04a604de-8b52-4cd8-a394-6286f00b438d_35.jpg',
          // This marker is 35 pixels wide by 35 pixels high.
          size: new google.maps.Size(35, 35),
          // The origin for this image is (0, 0).
          origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
          // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at (0, 32).
          anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 35)
        };
  var clickMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    icon: image,
    label: {
      text: "50€",
      color: 'white',
      fontSize: '15px',
      fontWeight: 'bold'
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use google maps built in info window. Here is an example in jQuery:

```
var infoContent = "<h1>Your Detailed Information Here</h1>";

var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: infoContent
});

marker.addListener('click', function () {
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
});
```

*You can then style the info window how you like with CSS*

Comment: yes i am using that, but what i need is price in the marker not when clicking on it

Comment: Will a title work for you next to the marker? See example here:  map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("$27.56")); If not then you will have to replace the image dynamically with SVG.

Comment: i have title for marker, i need like image i post so how can i do it?

Comment: I assume you do not have a bunch or pre built images, correct? so you wan to "make them and inject them dynamically, right?"

Comment: now i am showing a simple marker with only one letter, i want to show a marker with text only this

Comment: Check out answer 1 on this thread, that should get you where you are trying to go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33321440/google-maps-api-add-custom-svg-marker-with-label